# What does the "two-man" folder icon mean?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, icons

My folder icon usually looks like this:

[image]

However, I have a folder (in the location **%appdata% \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Start Menu \ Programs**) that looks like this:

[image]

What does that icon mean?

What is causing  this folder to have a special icon?

Comment: That overlay icon indicates that the folder is shared. [More info here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-get-shared-folder-icon-back-in-windows-explorer-in-windows-7/) and [here](http://www.fortop-digital.com/product/win7-shared-folder-icon/). To verify this, you may enter the following command in the command prompt: `net share`. If you see the folder listed in the output, then you can be sure that it means the folder is shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you'd specified which OS you're running (Windows 7, 8, 8.1, etc.)... but... I believe this means that the indicated folder will appear in all users' start menus.

I see this on my machine (Windows 8.1), not for that folder, but for `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows` - meaning that the Start Menu and everything else under `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows` form system-wide additions to the corresponding per-user directories.

(Edited - added:) To the OP: Please open a command prompt and type net share - if the folder shows up in the resulting list, it's a network share. If it doesn't, it's as described above, something Windows is doing to tell you "this folder is visible in all users' start menus". However, I have to say that I can't reproduce this on a Vista test machine. That is, the folder in question IS the system-wide Start Menu, but it doesn't appear with the "two-man" icon.

Comment: It's tagged Windows Vista.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a shared folder?

Comment: On my machine? Yes, very sure - not only would I never have shared such a thing, I checked the sharing tab under Properties... no, it isn't shared.

Comment: Pacerier: Indeed it is tagged as Vista. Sorry, I missed the tag

Answer (score 1):

It is a shared folder. More info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770406.aspx)

Comment: Could be... I don't remember what Vista uses for the shared folders icon.. but the "all users" explanation makes more sense for this case. I'll have to wait until Sunday or so to check my Vista installation.

Comment: I think it's actually the same. It is shared with other users on the compter so it will appear in the start menu of other users.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my answer above. But it isn't "shared" in the sense of "Windows file and printer sharing", which is the subject of the MS article you linked. Look in the folder's properties, Sharing tab; if it was "shared" in the network sense, it would show up there. (Too few words used for too many different meanings... not Microsoft's only offense of this type!!)

Comment: It is shared in de same way as if you shared other folders. But this one is shared to local users instead of network users. So it IS a shared folder, but it is not a network share. That does the icon mean as you asked.

Comment: Well, hm. I just set up a Vista test VM and I don't see that icon on that folder. In the OP's case it may be a network shared folder after all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question when this happened to me last night (Windows 7 Home Premium).

In my situation, I had shared a folder a while ago with someone on Dropbox. I then moved the folder to an external hard disk. The folder was no longer shared but retained the icon.

I used the right-click Properties menu and changed the icon to a plain folder.

I realize this is five years too late to be of use, but perhaps it may help someone else.

LP

Answer (score -2):

Properties>> Sharing >> advance setting >> uncheck share this forder (top left corner). 
This works in windows 10