# Windows folder with green icon and two people?

Tags: icons

What does this icon represent?  I've shared folders before but they never have this icon overlay.  Why does this folder have this icon overlay?

[image]

Comment: The two people means sharing, but the arrows... not sure. Is it shared using something like dropbox, onedrive, etc?

Comment: No drop box no onedrive, I do know some of our network is composed of linux machines and I am viewing this folder icon on a windows machine?  I wonder if that folder is actually on a linux system being shared to windows?

Comment: Maybe it means you can read and write in this folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "two-man" folder icon mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/349393/what-does-the-two-man-folder-icon-mean)

Comment: There is only a single icon overlay in the screenshot.  The double green arrow icon overlay.  The "two-man" icon indicates the folder is being shared.  There is some program installed on your system that is using the overlay.  If you are not an Administrator on the network, you should ask your IT staff, to identify what program that icon belongs to.  Please edit your question to include any application that might be using a icon overlay so a proper answer can be provided.

Comment: Ended up being the NFS Service from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following procedure can perhaps help you identify the origin of these icon overlays:

- Download and install [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)
- Launch ShellExView
- Click on the "Type" column to sort
- Scroll to the entries where Type is "Icon Overlay Handler"
- You will see the overlay image on the left, and the name of the product under Extension Name

[image]

Comment: Aren’t overlays usually restricted to the corner? This appears to be a completely different folder icon. I’m guessing nothing related to icon overlays will show up.

Comment: @Appleoddity: That would be even easier: Right-click on the icon, Properties and then "Change Icon..." will point to the executable containing the icon.

Comment: Thanks - ended up being the NFS service from windows.