# What does plus icon mean at the bottom of folder icon in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 shows every folder icon with a `+` sign.

[image]

At my others PCs there is no `+`.

Could someone tell me what does it mean and how to hide it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows folder with green icon and two people?](https://superuser.com/questions/1464376/windows-folder-with-green-icon-and-two-people)

Answer (score 0):

This is an icon overlay. Here is how to identify it:

- Download and install [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)
- Launch ShellExView
- Click on the "Type" column to sort
- Scroll to the entries where Type is "Icon Overlay Handler"
- You will see the overlay image on the left, and the name of the product under Extension Name

[image]